# Spread operator redorders array alphabetical

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a reducer which updated a field's value inside an array like so:

```
return {
   ...state,
   [action.field]: { ...state[action.field], value: action.payload }
};
```

This works fine but my state is an array of named objects (I think these are called object literals) like so:

```
export const state: any = {

    "account_name": {
        label: 'Account Name',
        type: 'text',
        name: 'account_name',
        value: '',
        required: true
    },

    "account_website": {
        label: 'Website',
        type: 'url',
        name: 'account_website',
        value: '',
        required: false
    },
```

My reducer works fine and updates the object as required, however it reorders the entire array in alphabetical order.

However if I change my update function to the following it works fine:

```
state[action.field] = action.payload
return state
```

Comment: That's not an array (an ordered collection), it's an object (a string->value mapping). You shouldn't necessarily trust objects to retain their key order. If you need order, use an array.

Comment: I just see an object, no array. Key order in objects generally shouldn't be an issue. Is there an issue for you if the keys are sorted?

Comment: If you need an object to be in a specific order you should use `Map` instead.

Comment: `state[action.field] = action.payload` would actually be considered a state mutation and should be avoided. As we've previously stated, within object literals, key-value order is rather irrelevant. If you need the data sorted in a specific way then do that when selecting it out of redux state or right before rendering it in the UI, or use a data structure that lends itself maintaining insertion order, like [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing my object (string->value mapping) to a regular array like so:

```
export const newAccountFields: any = [

    {
        label: 'Account Name',
        type: 'text',
        name: 'account_name',
        value: '',
        required: true,
    },
    {
        label: 'Contact',
        type: 'contacts',
        name: 'account_contact',
        value: '',
        required: true,
    },
```

Then when using the reducer my order is unchanged